# OpenCV - Extracting arrows from chart

Tags: c++, opencv

I'm trying to perform OpenCV on a flow chart to extract the structure (image 1). All images are computer generated. I can extract the blocks fine, and remove them from the image so we are just left with the arrows (image 3).

The issue is I'm unsure how to extract the connections. I.e. when I apply HoughLinesP there is large number of lines generated for each arrow (image 2). Does anyone know a method of extracting the lines such that I only get one 'line' for each arrow extracted?

[image: Original image]
[image: HoughLinesP applied to arrows]
[image: Arrows segmented from image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the image has no noise, using Hough transform is not optimal.

I would binarize the image so that I get all non-white pixels from the image.
Then, using a matched filter, I would find vertical and horizontal line segments.
Arrows in any of the four directions can be found in a similar fashion.

Filter for a line of 2 pixels thickness can be something like:

```
0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0
1 1 1 1 1 1
1 1 1 1 1 1
0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0
```

Comment: Interesting idea although different images will feature different arrows and line widths. Im wondering how i can obtain the line thickness without having a user option to define the number of pixels width.

Comment: You can always run multiple filters with varying thicknesses, and collect a histogram of number of matches.

Comment: Thanks this worked great. I filtered horizontal and vertical lines, then found the contours of the lines. By using the bounding box of the lines I could then search for the closest lines to connect them together. Gives good results, much better than HoughLinesP for my application.

Comment: hi @Jimwalks, can you please share your updated code for the flowchart connections extraction?